# Finding two missing card corners under perspective

Tags: projective-geometry

If I take a photo of a rectangular playing card, I can reconstruct the screen/photo-space position of one missing corner which lies outside the photo (outside the camera frustum): assuming simple perspective projection and no lens distortion, I just intersect the two lines along the adjacent edges, since perspective projection preserves lines.

Is it possible to reconstruct the screen-space position of *two* missing corners -- an entire missing edge -- that fell outside the camera frustum, given:

- the screen position of the two known corners, with one full edge between them
- the card dimensions (e.g. 3" x 5" -- probably the aspect ratio is more important than the actual dimensions here?),
- a guess at whether the full edge is a "long edge" or "short edge", and
- the angles observed at the two corners, as well as
- a model of the camera frustum (e.g. horizontal and vertical field of view angles, and/or sensor dimensions and focal point distance -- do we need this model at all)?

Intuition seems to indicate that the angles formed at the known corners would be a good indicator of the general direction of perspective, as well as the "magnitude of the perspective division" (please excuse any incorrect terminology).

It also seems like I could potentially work to try to find the card face normal vector in camera-relative 3D space given this information, and possibly extrapolate from there, but I'm a little stumped.

OpenCV uses a set of four $x, y$ point pairs to solve a system of linear equations in its `getPerspectiveTransform` method.  I've tried supplementing this with various other "known" information here, while leaving half of two point pairs unknown, but I run into missing information or an inability to get from what I have to what I need.

If there's not a single or few possible solutions (sounds like that's the case, see comments), **what form would the space of possible solutions take**?  What additional information could be provided to narrow the solution to a few roots or fewer DOF?

(From the computer vision side of things, this is probably the entirely wrong approach to take to a card recognition problem -- something like a feature extractor+descriptor+matcher is much more likely to be the right decision, based on what I'm reading -- but I'm curious about a possible analytical solution!)

(I've been wandering around searching for writing on rigid bodies and quads under perspective transforms, but have been having a little bit of trouble fitting what I'm reading to this particular problem; any other references/suggestions would be appreciated as well.)

Comment: There was one answer here saying this is impossible -- too many DOF with a rectangle -- but possible with squares, if you know the horizon.  It promised an image, but the answer has since disappeared, sadly.  =(  If a 1-or-2 DOF solution space is possible, it may get me close enough...

Comment: It looks as if http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Perspect/Perspect.htm#UsingVP has the basics for doing this with square/grid items; working through to try to see if it can possibly apply to rectangles.